# Python can't find No such element

Tags: python, selenium, selenium-chromedriver

I am trying trying to make an auto checkout script but i am stuck with selecting a specific size from a dropdown list

```
from selenium import webdriver
import requests

driver = webdriver.Chrome()
driver.get('http://www.supremenewyork.com/shop/all')
driver.find_element_by_xpath('//*[@id="container"]/article[112]/div/a').click()
driver.find_element_by_xpath('//*[@id="size"]/option[2]').click()
```

Below is the html of the dropdown size selection  and I am copying the xpath but still can't locate element , why ?

[image]

Answer (score 1):

Take a look at the [`Select`](http://selenium-python.readthedocs.io/navigating.html#filling-in-forms) class. You should be using it any time you are dealing with a SELECT element ... it will make your life much easier.

Your code should look like

```
from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import Select
select = Select(driver.find_element_by_id('size'))
select.select_by_visible_text("Medium")
```

Comment: Used this code and it throws me selenium.common.exceptions.NoSuchElementException: Message: no such element: Unable to locate element: {"method":"id","selector":"size"}

Comment: The above answer should be fine if your element is exist all the time, if maybe your element need some time to be loaded, then in that case WebDriverWait is the way to go
To take it futher, WebdriverWait IMHO should be the recommended way to locate element, it adds process of waiting and polling until element shown.

`element = WebDriverWait(driver, timeout).until(expected_conditions.visibility_of_element_located(By.ID, "size"))
select = Select(element)
select.select_by_visible_text("Medium")`

Answer (score 0):

For drop downs you cannot use driver.findElement directly. You should be using the Select api. 
In Java, 
`Select sel = new Select (driver.findElement (By.name ("size"))
sel.selectByvalue or index or visible text` can be used. You can refract ur code to python.. above is java code.

Answer (score 0):

Try below code.

```
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.support.select import Select
from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait
from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By

browser = webdriver.Chrome()
browser.get('http://www.supremenewyork.com/shop/all')
browser.find_element_by_xpath('//*[@id="container"]/article[12]/div/a/img').click()
WebDriverWait(browser,10).until(EC.visibility_of_any_elements_located((By.ID,'size')))
select = Select(browser.find_element_by_id('size'))
select.select_by_visible_text("Large")
```